# Loop through two dates columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to loop through table has two dates column

My table like

```
 id        from               to
 1       01/01/2021        03/01/2021
 1       06/01/2021        07/01/2021
```

I expect result as

```
id             date
1            01/01/2021
1            02/01/2021
1            03/01/2021
1            06/01/2021
1            07/01/2021
```

Comment: And what did you do that didn't work?

Comment: Join a calendar table/cte.

Comment: You need to count the days between the two dates and join with a numbers/tally table to duplicate the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Given a tally table (a table with a single integer column that goes up to a bazillion or whatever you need), you cross join this using the number of days between your two dates:

```
with n as (select * from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))x(n)) /* represents a tally table */

select id, DateAdd(day,n.n,[from]) [date]
from t
cross join n
where n.n <= DateDiff(day,[from],[to])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unfold such date ranges via a recursive CTE query

> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t
> CREATE TABLE #t (Id int, Fromdate datetime , Todate datetime)
> INSERT INTO #t (Id, Fromdate, Todate)
> VALUES ( 1,'2021/01/01','2021/01/03'),
>        ( 1,'2021/01/06','2021/01/07'), 
>        ( 2,'2021/02/01','2021/02/02')
> ```

> ```
> WITH RCTE_DATES AS (
>  SELECT Id, FromDate, ToDate
>  , 1 AS Lvl
>  , FromDate AS Dt
>  FROM #t
>  UNION ALL
>  SELECT Id, FromDate, ToDate
>  , Lvl + 1
>  , DATEADD(day, 1, Dt)
>  FROM RCTE_DATES 
>  WHERE Dt < ToDate
> ) 
> SELECT Id, Dt
> FROM RCTE_DATES
> ORDER BY Id, Dt
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Dt                     
> -: | :----------------------
>  1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000
>  1 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00.000
>  1 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00.000
>  1 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00.000
>  1 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00.000
>  2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000
>  2 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9d00f341ac49808588cc2d99860a024)*

Answer (score 0):

Every database should have some tally table to solve those problems...

A general fact is that "in a RDBMS database you will only retrieve the data that you have inserted" You will never find data that have not been put inside the DB...

Pesonnaly I ever create a number table, and also a calendar table. All those tally table are filled once before the database exploitation with all the rows that will be needed for query purpose.

As an example for your problem, a simple table like :

```
CREATE TABLE T_CALENDAR (CLD_DATE    DATE PRIMARY KEY);
DECLARE @D DATE = '2020-01-01';
WHILE @D < '2050-12-31'
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO T_CALENDAR (CLD_DATE) VALUES (@D);
   SET @D = DATEADD(day, 1, @D);
END;
```

The finest way is to store this table into a readonly storage (filegroup in MS SQL Server) because dates won't change... This avoid locking!

Then, solving your query is a child work :

```
SELECT CLD_DATE
FROM   MyTable AS T
       JOIN T_CALENDAR AS C ON T.MyDate BETWEEN "from" AND "to";
```

By the way, the use of SQL keyword as SQL identifier (table name, colum name...) is a bad idea !